# Nesting a DataFrame inside a MultiIndex DataFrame by adding level to the MultiIndex

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a DataFrame with MultiIndex columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([[100,100],[10,20],[1,3]]),
                 data=np.random.random(12).reshape(6,2))
df
```

[image: example dataframe]

Now I have a function that calculates a new DataFrame for each column of the original DataFrame:

```
def get_df(col):
    return pd.DataFrame({'Double':df[col]*2,'Triple':df[col]*3})
```

What I want is to create a new DataFrame `dg`, which replaces the original data in the columns of `df` by inserting the calculated DataFrame at each column of the original DataFrame, expanding the number of columns as needed, and adding a new level to the column MultiIndex.

I can easily create a new DataFrame `dg` with the columns I need, then fill them in in a loop:

```
dg = pd.DataFrame(columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([list(df.columns), ['Double','Triple']]))
for col in df.columns:
    dg[(col,'Double')] = get_df(col)['Double']
    dg[(col,'Triple')] = get_df(col)['Triple']
dg
```

This is the result:

[image: dg]

It is not quite what I wanted, because the MultiIndex has collapsed to just two levels (instead of 4), and it's not elegant. There has to be a better way to accomplish this in one step.

Answer (score 0):

If the requirement to run a function strictly on a column and return a data frame is not essential, then we could do the following:

```
def Double(x): return x*2
def Triple(x): return x*3

df = df.apply([Double, Triple])
```

I define `Double` and `Triple` in such a way that Pandas can use their names in the new output level:

[image: multilevel output]